# How can I configure the path Quarkus uses for openapi and health?

Tags: openapi, quarkus

As an experiment I am migrating a Spring Boot service to Quarkus.

In the Spring service all the Spring-provided endpoints (including swagger and health) are under /manage (it makes it easy for us to prevent external access to them).

I can see how to change the path for Swagger UI in Quarkus, and I can see how to change the base path for RESTeasy, but I can't see any way to change the paths for the other Quarkus-provided endpoint.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:

- quarkus.resteasy.path=/api
- quarkus.smallrye-health.root-path=/manage/health
- quarkus.smallrye-openapi.path=/manage/openapi

It seems Quarkus has 'secret' (well, build-time) dependencies on deployment components like [SmallRyeHealthProcessor.java](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/extensions/smallrye-health/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/smallrye/health/deployment/SmallRyeHealthProcessor.java).
Once that's been located it's pretty simple to find the Config class that contains the path.

Comment: Quarkus 0.17.0 also has support for Microprofile Health 2.0 which gives you more control. See https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/2555